# zk MVC to MVVM migration

Tags: mvvm, zk

At present my project designed with zk MVC pattern where a page looks like
    
    
    
     
    
   The corresponding Java implementation

```
SampleFenericFwdComposer extends GenericForwardComposer{
     doAfterCompose(Window win){
       super.doAfterCompose();
       .....
     }
       onClick$someButton(Event evt){....}
       onSelect$sampleListbox(Event evt) {....}
       private mehtods
       ....
   }
DAO classes using Hibernate for dataModel which will be rendered for each page
SampleEntity1 implements Serializable{
 accessors , mutators
}
```

Please let me know how to move to MVVM. MVVM pattern says use ViewModel pojo to bind with page. If so is tat my "SampleEntity1" class should be used as 'ViewModel' ? 
    If so , it not a good pattern as far im concerned....

Answer (score 0):

it's wide question. I think SampleEntity1 is a Model rather then ViewModel. You should create a new ViewModel which would have reference to Model.
Interpreting your code I would say that:

- SampleFenericFwdComposer - should be a View - SampleFenericFwdComposerView
- SampleFenericFwdComposerViewModel - should be pass to View by DataContext,
- SampleEntity1 - should be a Model and ViewModel should reference to it only.

Comment: the composer would just be altered to a viewmodel.  the events are done in the zul with annotations like `@command` and also in the viewmodel the corresponding method has annotation `@Command`